# How to pull out the existing Ag Grid Filter from the sideBar into its own modal?

Tags: reactjs, filter, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How would I create a custom AG Grid Filter modal? I want to keep the same built in functionality that Ag Grid provides with the Filter that's in the side tool panel; however, I want it to be in its own modal and not in the sideBar toolPanel. Is there a way to take the existing Filter component out of the sideBar toolPanel and have it exist as its own button? Or any easy way to use the existing Filter functionality to create a new Filter modal?

I would expect there to be a way using the API to pull the Filter component out of the sideBar toolPanel and have it be controlled by a custom modal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.